# How to join generic Vector into a String in Rust

Tags: rust

I am new to `Rust`, and I want to implement a generic function that creates a `String` from a `Vec` of any type that is convertable to `String`.

I tried the following:

```rust
pub fn myjoin<T>(iter: Vec<T>, s: &'static str) -> String
where
    T: ToString + std::fmt::Debug,
{
    iter.join(s);
}
```

As you can see, I bounded `T` to `ToString` to make sure the type can be converted to `String`, is this okay ?

Regarding the main question, I get the following error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `join` exists for struct `Vec<T>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/file.rs:145:14
    |
145 |         iter.join(s);
    |              ^^^^ method cannot be called on `Vec<T>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `[T]: Join<_>`
```

I am not able to fix this, can anyone explain to me the idea behind the error ?

Also, after fixing the issue, I want to make the separator a given type same as `T`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you can see, I bounded T to ToString to make sure the type can be converted to String, is this okay ?

No.

As the compiler error message tells you, the `join` method is provided by [the `Join` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.Join.html). For a `String` output, the only implementation is

```rust
impl<S> Join<&str> for [S]
where
    S: Borrow<str>,
type Output = String
```

So you can only `join(&str)` a slice of elements which deref' to `str` (more or less), it doesn't matter that you can *convert* them to strings.

If you want a more arbitrary conversion, you need an other path, specifically [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CString%3E-for-String):

```rust
impl FromIterator<String> for String
```

This means you can [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) an `Iterator<Item=String>` (or `Iterator<Item=&str>`) into a `String`:

```rust
pub fn myjoin<T>(iter: Vec<T>, s: &'static str) -> String
where
    T: ToString,
{
    iter.into_iter().map(|v| v.to_string()).collect()
}
```

But of course the issue then is there is the separator is missing. [An `Iterator::intersperse` is planned](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.intersperse) but not stable yet, [there is one in itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.intersperse.html) so if you can use that the problem is solved, kinda:

```rust
intersperse(iter.into_iter().map(|v| v.to_string()), s.to_string()).collect()
```

having to copy `s` for each separator is a bit expensive, a good alternative is that the stdlib `impl FromIterator<Cow<'a, str>> for String` so:

```rust
intersperse(
    iter.into_iter().map(|v| Cow::Owned(v.to_string())), 
    Cow::Borrowed(s),
).collect()
```

this way we *should* avoid the extra allocations.

If `itertools` is not an option, things get more complicated, I'd say the simplest is to desugar the entire thing:

```rust
use std::fmt::Write;

pub fn myjoin<T>(iter: Vec<T>, s: &'static str) -> String
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    let mut items = iter.into_iter();
    let Some(first) = items.next() else {
        return String::new();
    };
    let mut out = first.to_string();
    for it in items {
        write!(out, "{}{}", s, it).unwrap();
    }
    out
}
```

it's a bit workmanlike, but it does the job. Note that I switched to using `Display` (which is generally what `ToString` calls so not much of a restriction) in order not to have to allocate intermediate strings.

Doing the same with iterator chain is possible, but I'm not sure it's superior as you still need to deal with boundary conditions, you end up with something along the lines of:

```rust
pub fn myjoin<T>(iter: Vec<T>, s: &'static str) -> String
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    zip(
        once(Cow::Borrowed("")).chain(repeat(s.into())),
        iter.into_iter().map(|it| Cow::Owned(it.to_string())),
    )
    .flat_map(|(a, b)| [a, b])
    .collect()
}
```

there are almost certainly other ways to do it e.g.

```rust
pub fn myjoin<T>(iter: Vec<T>, s: &'static str) -> String
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    iter.into_iter()
        .map(|v| Cow::Owned(v.to_string()))
        .scan("", |st, v| {
            Some(if st.is_empty() {
                *st = s;
                [Cow::Borrowed(""), v]
            } else {
                [Cow::Borrowed(*st), v]
            })
        })
        .flatten()
        .collect()
}
```

but you get the gist.

Incidentally, itertools [also has a `join` function which uses display](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.join.html), so in reality if you can use itertools... you don't even need `myjoin` at all:

```rust
pub fn myjoin<T>(iter: Vec<T>, s: &'static str) -> String
where
    T: std::fmt::Display,
{
    itertools::join(iter, s)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solutions, any advice for mastering what you just provided ?

Comment: What do you mean "mastering"?

Comment: I want to get to that pro level of understanding all internal ideas and know what traits, fn, etc to use

Comment: That's mostly just experience, and watching talks or presentations / streams of people like Jon Gjengset. Maybe some of the more advanced books as well (like Programming Rust, or Gjengset's own Rust for Rustaceans). Taking trips through the standard library, or looking at the most popular crates, is also useful to know what's out there and available even if you don't have a use for it. Looking at codebases as well though it can be a bit hit or miss (as the codebase might not be great, or it might be way too complicated for your level).